# Messaging out a vector of names with quotation mark and commas in R

Tags: r, function

I have a vector of names of unknown length (i.e., comes from and depends on a function). I want this vector of name to be displayed e.g., like `'group.name','outcome', 'study.name'` and so on.

Is there a way to achieve this in R?

A toy example follows:

```
a <- c("group.name", "outcome", "study.name") 


message("\nNote: Variable(s)/moderator(s) ", dQuote(a), " detected as 'study.level'.\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toString()`:

```
message("\nNote: Variable(s)/moderator(s) ", toString(dQuote(a)), " detected as 'study.level'.\n")

Note: Variable(s)/moderator(s) “group.name”, “outcome”, “study.name” detected as 'study.level'.
```